# How to retrieve information from a jTextField

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtextfield, parseint

I am working on a personal project. I am creating a punch clock program so the part that I need help with, is where the user inputs the uid in the jTextField. So, I need to retrieve the uid(#######) and then search for that uid in the database with a sql statement. So this is what I have so far. the problem is that there is a red line under jTextField1.getText and when and when I run it, says =

`"setInt(int,int) in java.sql.PreparedStatement cannot be applied to (int,java.lang.String) pstmt.setInt(1, jTextField1.getText());"`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE STUDENTID = ?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setInt(1, jTextField1.getText()); // Retrieve uid from jTextField
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            String first = rs.getString(2);
            String last = rs.getString(3);
            String hours = rs.getString(6);

            fName.setText(first);
            lName.setText(last);
            tHours.setText(hours);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Student.this, err.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: SORRY!! the problem is that there is a red line under jTextField1.getText and when and when I run it, says = "setInt(int,int) in java.sql.PreparedStatement cannot be applied to (int,java.lang.String)
            pstmt.setInt(1, jTextField1.getText());"

Comment: [off-topic]: Is this method called by the EDT? You probably don't want to do this i/o in the EDT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29), the `setInt()` method takes in both parameters as `int`.

```
public void setInt(int parameterIndex,
                   int x)
```

So,You need to change this:

```
 pstmt.setInt(1, jTextField1.getText());
```

to:

```
 pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
```

because the `getText()` method [returns a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29).

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Gaara I appreciate your generous help. Now it works, this is lovely.

Answer (score 6):

`jTextField1.getText()` will return String use `parseInt` to convert to an int

```
pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
```